# Quickly retrieving the last row from a SAS index

Tags: indexing, sas

I have a very large table that contains an ID field and a datetime field.  The table is ordered by the ID field, and INDEXED on the datetime field.

I want to quickly find the maximum datetime value but I can't find any good way to do this.

**Sample data:**

```
data x;
  do id=1 to 10000000;
    created_datetime = datetime() + (ranuni(1)*100000);
    output;
  end;
  format created_datetime datetime22.;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  create index created_datetime on x;
quit;
```

**Attempt #1: `PROC SQL` and the `max()` function**

For some reason I thought that this would instantly return the result but I found what actually happens was counter-intuitive (to me at least).  Using the `max()` function doesn't use an index - it can't!  Where clauses etc can make use of indexes but the max() function can't.  Even if you force the use of an index it's still going to process all rows in the table, just in the order that using the index returns them.

```
option msglevel=i;
proc sql noprint;
  select max(created_datetime) from x(idxname=x);
quit;
```

**Attempt #2: By-group processing**

The below easily returns the first row using an index:

```
data min; 
  set x;
  by created_datetime;
  output;
  stop;
run;
```

But I can't use the descending keyword to work backwards through the list to get the last row:

```
data min; 
  set x;
  by descending created_datetime;
  output;
  stop;
run;
```

SAS also doesn't seem to support descending indexes, so I can't use that approach either.

**Attempt #3: Use metadata about the index and a `WHERE` statement**

I looked in `SASHELP.VINDEX` hoping that maybe the max values might be stored in the metadata somewhere that I could then use in a where statement.  No luck there.

**EDIT :**

**Attempt #4: `PROC SQL` with `inobs` or `outobs`**

@DomPazz's below answer inspired me to revisit some other SQL based solutions.  I thought perhaps the `order by` statement in `PROC SQL` may interact with the inobs or outobs options to achieve my goal.  It didn't work though.  The ordering looks like it is applied to the output of the query and in no way affects the order in which the rows are actually read in.

```
/* Uncomment options as necessary */
proc sql noprint /*inobs=1 outobs=1*/;
  create table temp as 
  select created_datetime
  from x
  order by created_datetime desc;
quit;
```

Help!

Comment: How continuous is this datetime field?  Do you have basically individual index records, or is the datetime really storing something larger and you have many records per same datetime value?

Comment: It's possible to have multiple records for a given datetime - even to the millisecond.

Comment: Possible, sure, but is it normal?

Comment: Yes it occurs often.  I don't normally look at the millisecond values because I will truncate them when bringing the data into SAS.  We don't need that level of granularity for how we use the data.

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'normal' though.  It probably happens <1% of the time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the value of an index, then.  Your index is bigger than the dataset.  It's not saving you any time at all (and thus isn't used).

Comment: Is the file sorted?  If it isn't sorted, then the index is completely useless in this case.  If it is sorted, then just grab the last row (using NOBS).

Comment: The index is typically used for queries such as - find all rows between <startdate> and <enddate>.  I'm not sure I understand what you mean because AFAIK having high cardinality in a field makes the field an ideal candidate for an index.  The table is sorted, but it's by the ID field, not by the date field.  The actual table in real-life also contains many other columns, so adding an additional column+index will consume perhaps an additional 5% of space at a rough guess.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose.  I would usually have a different table that stored just datetime and eventID or something like that, which would make this easier.

Comment: Yeah good point. That's what I've done in the past as well - I was looking for a nicer solution.  If SAS indexes provided features similar to other databases then the 2nd table approach wouldn't be required either.  Provided space isn't an issue, IMO this approach will be cleaner (less code, 1 less table, no chance of getting out of sync if 2nd table isn't updated).  It only requires an additional index to be created, and one additional field to exist.

Comment: Was pretty sure there was a contents way, but had to find Michael Raithel's paper to remember what it was.  (His book is a very detailed read if you haven't read it yet, by the way - the complete guide to SAS indexes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives you the centiles - the last one should be the 100% mark.  This requires the index to have been recreated using the `UPDATECENTILES` option after any additions/deletions to the data.

```
proc contents data=have centiles;
run;
```

You can grab that with ODS OUTPUT if you want it as a dataset (the output table name is "INDEXES"):

```
ods output indexes=temp;
proc contents data=have centiles ;
run;
```

See Michael Raithel's papers, in particular [The Basics Of Using SAS Indexes](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/247-30.pdf), for more details.

Comment: According to a test I just ran, you probably would have to update the centile specifically.  I tried the above using the 95% centile value, and SAS replied it was not using the index because the data wasn't sorted.

Comment: Could you then use the max(datetime) value from `temp` in your example in a `where` clause against the original dataset to verify the max value? The `MAX` this time would exploit the index and should be faster than an all-table `MAX`.

Comment: Unfortunately @mjsqu it doesn't seem to work that way. I ran a similar test and it was still comparable to an all table max since the dataset isn't sorted.

Comment: Shame @Joe, I remember figuring out a good way to use `CONTENTS` to speed up `MAX` with indexed SPD tables but that doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 1):

What I could do - since it is a datetime value, is create a new field containing the same value multiplied by -1, and then index the new field.  Ugly but it would work.

Pros:-

- Solves the issue.
- Simple - easily explained with some comments

Cons:-

- Wastes space with an additional field and index.
- Additional processing overhead associated with maintaining the index.
- Only works with numeric fields guaranteed to be >= 0
- It's an ugly hack
- probably lots of others...

Unless someone can think of a nicer approach I'll probably end up going with this.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct() uses the index.  On your example here, this is slower than your other methods, but for a really big table it might be faster.

```
proc sql noprint;
create table temp as 
    select distinct(created_datetime) as max
    from x
    order by max desc;
quit;

18003  proc sql noprint;
18004  create table temp as
18005      select distinct(created_datetime) as max
18006      from x
18007      order by max desc;
INFO: Index created_datetime of SQL table WORK.X selected for SQL SELECT DISTINCT/UNIQUE
      optimization.
NOTE: SAS threaded sort was used.
NOTE: Table WORK.TEMP created, with 9999865 rows and 1 columns.

18008  quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           2.97 seconds
      cpu time            4.54 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks Dom.  This solution isn't practical for my current issue, but your SQL approach inspired my below answer.